# Getting data source of Feature Layer object in Python script tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, data-source

I am writing a script tool to update some records.  I am wanting to use a feature layer as input, to maintain definition queries, selections, etc.  I would like to get the data source of the input feature layers, but I am unable to find a way.  For example,

```
in_fl = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
desc = arcpy.Describe(in_fl)
arcpy.AddMessage(desc.catalogPath)
```

prints out the following:

```
u'\\MyData.DBO.MyDataset\MyData.DBO.MyFeatureclass'
```

I would like to get the full path of the SDE feature class.  Is this possible?

Comment: I am open to being schooled here, but won't something like  this `fullpath = os.path.join(folderPath, in_fl)` work for SDE or do you mean something else when you say fullpath? I don't have an SDE to try it.

Comment: in_fl is a feature layer object, so I am looking for a method that provides the path. I could include an additional parameter to ask the user to provide the database path, but that seems silly if I can simply obtain that from the feature layer. A non-SDE feature layer provides the complete path with arcpy.Describe(in_fl).catalogPath.

Comment: I figured it had to be more complex than it appeared to me. But I thought I would give it a shot. `arcpy.Describe(in_fl).catalogPath` much simpler

Comment: By what do you mean "the full path of SDE feature class"?? You already have that -- connection plus table name.

Comment: @Vince That sounds like a good solution. Can you offer any code?

Comment: What about the .dataSource method? [This Esri technical article has an example.](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011530)

Comment: That applies to a Layer object.  However, when I obtain the layer object of my feature layer, it returns the same as .catalogPath.

Answer (score 2):

From Esri's [How To: Use Python to list the data sources of all layers in the table of contents of a map document](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011530):

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        print "Layer: " + lyr.name + "  Source: " + lyr.dataSource
```

It will look at all layers in your current mxd and print the name and data source